# Displaying links to Privacy Policy and terms of Use on App

Tags: gui-design, mobile, design, mobile-application

I'm creating a mobile app (for iPhone) for a product which has a website right now. 
The website Log In/sign up page consists of links to the Terms of Use, Privacy Policy, FAQ, consent Policy, Contact Us.

Upon opening these links you get a large document. These are important in case user wants to read each and everything before signing up and start using app. Such users might be in minority. But I guess its pretty important to display them unless you are prepared for this:
http://blog.ericgoldman.org/archives/2012/10/how_zappos_user.htm

My question is, What is the best way to display link to the Terms of use and other Legal things such that they dont escape from users sight?
Also some examples of apps who did it right

Thanks

Comment: You say you want to make sure your users read the Legal stuff before they sign up for your mobile app? How do you handle this on the web app? You say the links are on the login page but, where are they placed? What do they look like?

Comment: @MarkBubel Oh, as of now I have placed them in a slideout menu on the login screen. they appear only when the button which shows the slideout is tapped. Thus, they are not directly visible.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying Terms of use and other legal things should be somewhat catchy because normally people don't give it much attention. But to highlight these important terms either make a button named like "Usercare" or something like that but not using traditional approach if you really want users to read it before using your app.